# ¿Cómo puedo inhabilitar git-stripspace?

Tags: git

Quiero crear un commit de git con un mensaje con más de una línea blanca:

```
Mensaje ejemplo


Que tiene 2 lineas blancas.
```

Pero normalmente, cuando hago el commit, git pasa el mensaje por [git-stripspace](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stripspace/1.7.5), que elimina las lineas blancas multiples, con este resultado:

```
Mensaje ejemplo

Que tiene 2 lineas blancas.
```

¿Cómo puedo inhabilitar esta acción? Puede ser solo por un solo commit, o con configuración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando hagas el commit puedes elegir la opción:

```
--cleanup=verbatim
```

Por ejemplo:

```
git commit -F msg.txt --cleanup=verbatim
```

siendo *msg.txt*:

```
Este es un


mensaje


multilínea
```

Más info sobre la opción `cleanup` [aquí](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit/1.7.11.4).

Apéndice: Información sobre [cómo escribir un buen mensaje en un commit](https://git-scm.com/book/ch5-2.html#Commit-Guidelines).